# Text mining algorithm similar text

Tags: text, mining

Hi I am writing a small app using Facebook to group people by social networks. The main problem I face is grouping similar texts together. Some people have the education as  `Anna University, Guindy` while others put it as `Anna University`. How do I group these together? What algorithm or term should I search for?

Comment: It's hard to know when we aren't presented with more than one example, but my first thought was to google for Address-finding algorithms. Heard that they can be tweaked into a lot of cool things :)

Comment: You could try to search for Edit distance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance . I think I personally would've tried to solve it by reading through this page and then start my search:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem .. Last, and maybe least, depending on how much you know about how they are created, you can do multiple substrings of the strings and then regexp them, giving procentual points and slowly erase strings with low points.